# Import a 5160 label into Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, ubuntu-mate

I would like to create Avery 5160 labels.

When I use New, Label, there is no pick for that label.

Can it be imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly answer the question: yes, you can import that template. The link to the template is at the bottom of this answer.

If you'd rather not download a (possibly) duplicate template, you should be able to find the correct template where you are looking. After clicking **New > Labels** you should see two options in the bottom-right, labeled **Brand** and **Type**. Choose **Avery Letter Size** for **Brand** and **5160 Address** for **Type** (you may have to scroll down the list to see all available options).

If those options are not available to you, you can certainly download the template and import it into LibreOffice Writer directly. Avery's templates can all be found on their website, the specific template you're looking for can be found here: https://www.avery.com/templates/5160 . All that needs to be done is to open the file in LibreOffice Writer. Tested today on 18.04 with LibreOffice 6.0.7.3.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Appreciating that you have marked @Lou's reply as accepted, as an alternative to using LibreOffice for printing labels have you considered using gLabels downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Whilst I use LibreOffice for many things I found gLabels much more intuitive in its capabilities for handling labels, visiting cards and the like. The software is simply designed for the job and it is easy to setup .csv lists to import names and addresses. There is a bank of pre-defined labels to draw from but equally easy to design you own if required.

Comment: I will definitely try gLabels out.